# VB silverlight for windows phone "Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types"

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

When I am selecting a button from the .xaml file and then tap event from the right (in order to set the tap event) it auto generates this sub:

```
Private Sub btn(ByRef sender As Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles btn.Tap

End Sub
```

But it also has this error:

> Error  1   Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: i just noticed that when i am starting to type the name of the button, the autocomplete show an icond with a locked lock :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Public WithEvents btn As Button`
just above the  sub in order to send away the bug !