# handles clause requires a withevents variable defined in the containing type (Error in log, but disappears when clicked)

Tags: vb.net

I have spent many hours trying to solve this issue, I feel like I have tried almost everything I found online, so I will go about explaining the issue, and what I did.

Situation:

- I am working on a web app. Added to the solution by opening a web site on a local IIS
- Many of the aspx.vb files inside of it are having the error "Handles clause requires a WithEvents varaible defined in the
  containing type or one of its base types" after pressing the play button at the top. (not present when rebuilding)
- As soon as I click on the description to go to the error, all of these specific errors

Stuff I have tried:

- I have tried [VB silverlight for windows phone "Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615710/vb-silverlight-for-windows-phone-handles-clause-requires-a-withevents-variable), but it didn't work.
- changing the inherits tag, as well as the autoeventwriteup in the page tag (<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableViewState="True" CodeFile="frmBatchEdit.aspx.vb"
  Inherits="Administation_frmBatchEdit" Culture="auto" meta:resourcekey="PageResource1"
  UICulture="auto" %>)

At this point I could use any help I can get. What is annoying me most is seeing 2000+ of these in my project, and then to make it all disappear I have to remove one at a time. The website itself is very old, and I am wondering if it has something to do with the age of it, because each time I change something in a file, it will start showing this error in the future.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Do you have any references in your project that point to a higher version of .Net than your Web Application targets?

Comment: No, all projects are at 4.5.1, and the web app target framework is 4.5.1 as well